# Set android permissions based on current battery level

Tags: java, android, permissions, battery

I use

```
public int getBatteryLevelInPercentage(){
    return mBatteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
}
```

to get the current battery level of an android device.

I'm looking for a possible way to 'restrict' the usage of i.e. `"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"` namely to change it to `"android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"` when the battery level starts to dip below 30%

So something like

```
if(getBatteryLevelInPercentage() <= 30%) { changePermission()}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, or if it's even a good idea. I would appreciate greatly if you can share some of your ideas on how to deal with low battery in a good way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revoking permissions of an app will restart the entire app, which I'm guessing isn't what you're looking for. Instead, I suggest you limit the functionality of your app based on the received battery status.